# Spring Integration - Processing Pipeline - Design

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to design a message processing pipeline that needs to process a message using multiple end-points. At each stage, the endpoints returns either the payload (could be transformed) or an error message. Here's a generic example of what I have in my mind:

```
<int:payload-type-router input-channel="preprocessing-output">
        <int:mapping type="com.example.Error" channel="error" />
        <int:mapping type="com.example.PreprocessedDomainObject" channel="validation-input"/>
</int:payload-type-router>

<int:service-activator input-channel="validation-input"
        ref="validationService" method="validate" output-channel="validation-output"/>

<int:payload-type-router input-channel="validation-output">
            <int:mapping type="com.example.Error" channel="error" />
            <int:mapping type="com.example.CouldBeAnotherObject" channel="processor-input"/>
</int:payload-type-router>
```

So on, this processing chain can be quite long... Is there a better way to design this instead of a payload type router after every stage? Kinda feels redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd make it based on the exceptions. The validation service should just throw exception and all you need is to catch it on the caller or have an `errorChannel` if it is Inbound Channel Adapter.

That way you don't need those routers definitions at all and just plain services calling chain.